# Can not configure LESS in Apache (MAMP)

Tags: less, mime-types

I´m using MAMP and i´m trying to configure and use LESS for styiling mi websites.

I have this lines in my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />
<script src="js/less-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Both are linked correctly, but when I see the website...

```
FileError: 'http://localhost:8888/ejemplo/css/styles.less' wasn't found (404)
in styles.less
```

Searching in google I saw that maybe is problem with Mime-Types, so I configure the mime.types, .htacces and httpd.conf archives with this lines:

```
text/css                    less
AddType text/css .less
AddType text/css .less
```

Each line in each archive.

But doesn´t works!! I dont know more to do! HELP!

Comment: Ok, solved...
Dont know why, but solved... I tried to do that:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />

But not worked, so I undo that and put:

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />

And works... (and I eliminate all I addded of mime-types and works LOL)

Comment: the less.js compiler use the `rel="stylesheet/less"` attribute to find which file(s) should be compiled.